# Why aren’t anti-abortion laws unconstitutional since they force women to carry a pregnancy against their will?

Tags: abortion

If we are afforded the right to self-determination as well as protection against the actions of others that may threaten bodily integrity, wouldn’t it be unconstitutional for the state, by denying access to abortion, to force a woman to carry an unwanted pregnancy against their will and without their consent?

Comment: "*unwanted pregnancy against their will and without their consent?*" Except for medical reasons or instances of actual rape (not to confuse with sexual regret), having sex without precautions defeats allegations about will and consent. "*protection against the actions of others that may threaten bodily integrity*". The anti-abortion movement seeks, in part, to protect the fetus against procedures that interrupt its life.

Comment: I think your question lacks two important aspects: a) Not every pregnancy that shall be terminated is unwanted and b) What about the self-determination of the child?

Comment: @kisspuska Both abortion and medically assisted suicide are (under some conditions) legal in some countries nowadays. But I don't think the two are really comparable here, since not knowing the child's will is very different from someone that wants to end his life  voluntarily (eg due to poor health).

Comment: Laws that "force people to do things against their will" are not inherently unconstitutional.  We have all kinds of laws that "force" people to pay taxes, obey traffic laws, etc, whether they want to or not, and there is no doubt about their constitutionality.  In some sense, forcing people to do things that they may not want to, if it is for the greater good, is almost the entire point of having a government.  If you want to find constitutional arguments against abortion prohibition, you have to look elsewhere.

Comment: Carrying a pregnancy is such an underhanded attempt at dehumanizing the child that pregnant women carry

Comment: A truly deplorable use of language.

Comment: ...And it's not a child until its born, you are humanizing the fetus, and its not her demonizing what is not yet a human, and its cell culture does not function even as a sentient being capable of experiencing pain — the theoretical cut-off time of abortion.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the Constitution does not provide a freestanding right to "self-determination," to self-defense, or to bodily integrity. To the extent the courts recognize any of these as *implied* rights, they are subject to balancing against other rights or governmental authority.

Analogizing to the Second Amendment can be helpful. There's a lot of gray area in Second Amendment law, but it's pretty clear that I have a right to keep a knife on my bedstand, but not to build a nuclear arsenal in your backyard.

Why not? Because you have a right to keep people off your property, and because the government has an interest in protecting its citizens, infrastructure, and natural resources from the risks associated with my incompetent exercise of my Second Amendment rights.

So what interests are at stake in the abortion question? [*Roe*](https://casetext.com/case/roe-v-wade) held that women have a right to privacy that protects access to abortion, but it also recognized that the government has an interest in protecting potential life. The question was how to balance the privacy interest against the interest in protecting potential life.

*Roe* said the woman's rights generally outweigh the government's interests up until the point of viability, at which point the government's interests begin to outweigh the woman's privacy interests. But [*Dobbs*](https://s3.documentcloud.org/documents/21835435/scotus-initial-draft.pdf) appears poised to change that by saying that the woman's right to privacy does not exist at all. *Dobbs* likewise rejects the idea that the right to due process or any other constitutional right protects the right to abortion. Therefore, it concludes, a woman has no rights that can outweigh the state's interest in protecting the potential life she is carrying.

*Dobbs* also recognizes -- but does not take a position on -- the argument that a fetus is actually a person itself. If a legislature were to adopt that position, and the courts were to accept it, we would find ourselves in a position where whatever rights a woman has to self-determination and bodily integrity would have to be balanced against the fetus's rights to self-determination and bodily integrity.

Comment: That last para is a scary thought.

Comment: The second amendment has the advantage of being an explicit right. Roe found an implied right to privacy by considering all a citizen’s rights collectively. Basically, to effectively have *these* there must be this other, unwritten right to privacy. Dobson is saying that reading was wrong.

Comment: I would argue that prior to any systemic cerebral activity, the decision to abort is protected "speech" in the meaning of the First Amendment, and the government has no business in it — hence my comment previously about assisted suicide: Each are matters of self-determination, and self-determination only. The prior to systemic cerebral activity is no more than a cultivation of cells. Any other attribution already enter the territory of some sort of pre-determination of a life "meant to be". There is no human life until there is human life.

Comment: Any such presumptions is the government exercising religion and forcing it on its subjects. The protection a fetus deserves is analogous to that of animal cruelty laws: If it can sense pain, it must not be hurt, end of story. Get your Abrahamic ideals out of government and the life of those who don't share them.

Comment: I endorse about as broad an interpretation of free speech as anyone, and am about as uninterested in regulating abortion as anyone, but that argument makes no sense to me at all.

Answer (score -2):

If the question is broader and seeks any additional support of abortion beyond what is to be soon outruled, there is.

The First Amendment to the U.S. constitution not only protects speech in the literal sense, but protects "expressive conduct" more generally. This is true even if current theocrats of the U.S. Supreme Court resiliently refuse to acknowledge it.

A summary of the U.S. Court of Appeals for the 9th Circuit in *Edge v. City of Everett, Mun. Corp.* (9th Cir. 2019) 929 F.3d 657, 668 summarizes a number of U.S. Supreme Court decisions as follows:

> "The First Amendment literally forbids the abridgment only of ‘speech," ’ but the United States Supreme Court has "long recognized that its protection does not end at the spoken or written word." *Texas v. Johnson* , 491 U.S. 397, 404, 109 S.Ct. 2533, 105 L.Ed.2d 342 (1989). The Supreme Court refers to non-speech activity that is within the ambit of the First Amendment’s protections as "expressive conduct." See , e.g. , *Clark v. Cmty. for Creative Non-Violence* , 468 U.S. 288, 293, 104 S.Ct. 3065, 82 L.Ed.2d 221 (1984). Conduct that is "sufficiently imbued with elements of communication" is protected by the First Amendment"

A reasonable person should recognize that the Christianity-intoxicated political discourse around abortion resulted in a belief that one who believes in Almighty God would not support abortion because it is the killing of a child bla, bla, bla.

One who chooses abortion of a fetus prior to developing the ability of experiencing pain does nothing else then engages in conduct subject to (1) "an intent to convey a particularized message" [with (2)] "great" "likelihood ... that the message would be understood by those who viewed it." (*Texas v. Johnson* (1989) 491 U.S. 397, 404, 109 S.Ct. 2533)

Accordingly, so long as the mother decides at abortion in a State where it will have been prohibited, the message will be the result of a clear intent to convey the particularized message that one believes the prohibition of an otherwise not unreasonable abortion prior to any systemic cerebral activity or ability to pain which will be clearly understood when one shows up and explains that they are aware of the regulation yet they wish the abortion to be conducted putting the matter in the protection of the First Amendment.

Or else, they make the decision to seek such medical care in a clearly Christianity-oriented or yet worse: Funded hospital, and inform them that the mother presumes their position is that abortion is child murder yet you wish them to proceed, and if the reason to refuse is not the doctor's religious conviction, but State policy, then refusal would be the result of a violation of the right to engage in expressive conduct to convey a particular message with a great likelihood to be understood by its audience.

Now, this all, of course, does not matter because the ideologues of the courts with special importance here at the U.S. Supreme Court will, if they don't have one, create a loophole with force to get what they want through. So all of the above about Constitutional rights and case law are all [fugazi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HwOGd9fmoxg). It's their law, and they will tell you what it is.